# How is every subset of real numbers measurable despite the existence of a non-measurable set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We know the existence of nonmeasurable subsets of $\mathbb R$ by [Vitali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set), but many books and lecture notes on real analysis still include the statement that every subset of real numbers is measurable. What am I missing?

#### Context

On page 2 under the title General Constructions in [these notes](http://math.bme.hu/%7Enandori/Virtual_lab/stat/foundations/Measure.pdf), it is said that the collection of all subsets forms a sigma-algebra. On the other hand, every element of a sigma algebra is measurable by: Charalambos, Real Analysis (3rd edition), page 112, Theorem 15.3.

How to resolve this apparent contradiction?

Comment: every subset is outer measurable, maybe you need to check differing terminology among different sources

Comment: You should probably give an example of a precise statement from a specific book.

Comment: The OP included sufficient context for the question in the comments below.

Answer (score 4):

What the notes you linked to are saying is that it's always possible to form a $\sigma$-algebra consisting of all subsets of a set $S$ (which could be $\mathbf{R}$).

But when we talk about the theorem that there exist non-measurable subsets of reals, what we mean is that they are not Lebesgue-measurable.

That is, a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\mathbf{R}$ is defined in a certain way, and its members are called Lebesgue-measurable sets. The theorem then says that this particular $\sigma$-algebra does *not* consist of all subsets of $\mathbf{R}$.

EDIT: The definition of a "measurable" set in Aliprantis's book *Principles of Real Analysis, 3rd edition* (p. 112) that you mentioned is as follows.

"A subset $E$ of a measure space $(X, S, \mu)$ will be called *measurable* (more precisely $\mu$-measurable) if $E$ is measurable with respect to the outer measure $\mu^{*}$ generated by $\mu$."

The book considers $S$ here to be a semiring rather than a $\sigma$-algebra.

This is indeed the definition of a Lebesgue-measurable set, when a certain measure space $(\mathbf{R}, S, \mu)$ is chosen. Here $S$ consists of all intervals of the form $(a,b]$, and $\mu$ is defined by $\mu((a,b]) = b-a$.

The book continues:

"Every member of $S$ is measurable."

So what the book is saying is that every interval of the form $(a,b]$ is Lebesgue-measurable, not that every subset of $\mathbf{R}$ is.

Answer (score 2):

We usually construct Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ by first constructing an outer measure $\mu^*$ which *is* defined on all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. We then restrict to subsets $E$ which satisfy, for *any* set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, 
$$\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \cap E^c).$$
The collection of all such sets $E$ are what we call Lebesgue-measurable sets. Non-measurable sets do not satisfy this equality. After we restrict $\mu^*$ to these sets, we obtain a bona fide measure $\mu$, and $\mu$ is *not* defined on all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thanks for explanation, I know what you wrote above,but look at this, on page 2 under the title General Constructions: http://www.math.bme.hu/~nandori/Virtual_lab/stat/foundations/Measure.pdf                                                         On the other hand, every element of a sigma algebra is measurable by charalambos real analysis book page 112, Theorem 15.3

Comment: Could you give the title of the second book, with the edition? And do you mean Aliprantis?

Comment: Yes aliprantis, 3rd edition.

Comment: I know what you are trying to say to me, my concern is that there are still some vague expressions on certain books or lecture notes. Maybe they have to recover these phrases, or they have to explain what they meant by measurable in a very clear way.

Comment: I think if you want to understand a certain statement in a math book, you have to read the context, and pay special attention to the preceding definitions, in order to know what the author is saying. I didn't notice anything unclear in either of the two sources you cited.

Comment: Yes you are right, and I studied this book long time ago but what confused me is(I noticed this when I tried to remember something else), if \mu* is an extension to the whole power set of a given set X and Vitali's set is an element of  the power set, where would the image of this set go under the \mu*?but I understand it now.Thanks.